# How to set flags like --localInputDir in Myrrix war file?

Tags: tomcat, war, myrrix

After reading the docs of Myrrix, I want to know how to set flags like:

```
java -jar myrrix-serving-x.y.jar --localInputDir /path/to/working/dir --port 8080
```

when deploying as a .war file. I wonder how to set these `--` flags at Tomcat startup?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `web.xml` file found in the `.war` file that is generated. It looks like:

https://code.google.com/p/myrrix-recommender/source/browse/trunk/web-common/docs/WEB-INF/web.xml

This is how equivalent arguments are set in a WAR context.

Comment: Sean, could you elaborate a bit? I'm trying to activate the authentication this way but it doesn't seem to kick in. I've added the following params without any luck: https://gist.github.com/herrbuerger/7009531

Comment: If you're deploying as a .war file and declaring your settings in `web.xml`, then you have access to all the standard container security mechanisms. You should use things like `<security-constraint>` to configure security. This is what the embedded version is doing anyway.